# convert nested list to normal list using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How can I do the following in Python?

```
a = [2,[33,4],[2,3,4,6]]
li = [ i for i in a if isinstance(i,int) else j in i ]
```

how do i convert list a into a = [2,33,4,2,3,4,6]

I am able to do it with normal for loop but i want to use only list comprehension

Comment: Don't. A list comprehension isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [20]: [k for e in a for k in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e])]
    ...: 
Out[20]: [2, 33, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```